# Power series: convergence on right-open interval

Tags: power-series, formal-power-series

Given the power series $f(x) = \sum_{k\geq 1} a_k x^k$ where $a_k \geq 0$, is the following statement true?

> Let $f(x) = \sum_{k\geq 1} a_k x^k$ with $a_k \geq 0$. If $f(x) < \infty$ for some fixed $x \geq 0 $, then there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(x + \epsilon) < \infty$.

In other words, the above states that the supremum of $\{x \geq 0: f(x) < \infty\}$ is not attained.

Comment: No, it just states that the interval of convergence of the power series  is right open.

Comment: @PierreCarre: Thank you. I corrected the title.

Comment: I meant to say that your statement "In other words, the above states that there is no maximum value ..." is not correct. The result says that if the series is convergent for a given $x$ it will be convergent for $x +\varepsilon$. This does not mean that $x$ can be arbitrarily large. The interval of convergence could be $]-1,1[$.

Comment: I am not saying that $x$ can be arbitrarily large. Only that a maximum doesn't exist. Or in other words, the supremum of the set $\{x \geq 0: f(x) < \infty\}$ is not attained.

Comment: Ok, I did not understand that from what you wrote in the initial post.

Comment: OK. I have changed the wording now. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_k=k^k $ and $ x=0$. Conclusion : the statement is not true.

Comment: Thank you for the simple counter-example!

Comment: @FabianYing This example appears only due to a typo. Just change $x\geq0$ to $x>0$ to get a result with substance.

Comment: @logarithm Yes, that's true. I also found a counter-example for $x > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Fred already answered with a simple counter-example with $x=0$.

There is also a counter-example on the statement with $x > 0$ instead of $x \geq 0$.

Consider $a_k = 2^{2k} / k^2$, so 
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2k} x^k}{k^2}\,.
\end{equation}

This power series converges for $x \in [-1/4, 1/4]$ and diverges for $x < -1/4$ and $x >  1/4$.

To see this, you can apply the Ratio test to find

\begin{equation}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{|a_{k+1} x^{k+1}|}{|a_k x^k|} = 4 |x|\,,
\end{equation}

proving convergence in $x \in (-1/4, 1/4)$ and divergence for $x < -1/4$ and $x > 1/4$.
One can then check the convergence of the end points separately:

\begin{equation}
f(1/4) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} < \infty\,,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
f(-1/4) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k^2} < \infty\,.
\end{equation}
(The latter series converges because the absolute value series converges.)

Full details can be found in: http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/calculus/intervals-of-convergence/intervals-of-convergence.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider $a_k=1/k^2$ and $x=1$.